# What is the largest interval containing $0$ so that $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ has an inverse?

Tags: functions

What is the largest possible interval containing $0$ such that $f$ has an inverse on that interval, where $f(x)=(x+1)^2$?

I have tried to find the inverse and the derivative.

$f(x)$ is $0$ when $x=-1$.

$f$ derivative is $0$ when $x=-2$; is this the local minimum?

$f$ inverse is $0$  when $x=1$; is this the local maximum?

Comment: correction; -1 local minimum and local maximum 1. is that correct?

Comment: There is no local maximum.  $f(x)$ is invertible with the restriction on the domain $x\in [-2,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to admit a restricted inverse, one has to check injectivity (if a function is not injective in $(a,b)$ it for sure does not admit an inverse function in that interval).

Now, check that the function you gave is injective in the interval $(-\infty,-1]$ (for example check that the sign of the derivative there is always negative, therefore the function is decreasing, hence injective). Analogously, it is injective in $[-1,\infty)$ (change a bit the previous argument to conclude so).

Then, if I had to choose the “largest” interval containing zero for which f admits an inverse I’d go with $[-1,\infty)$, which geometrically corresponds to the right “half” of the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a function has an inverse if the domain is restricted so that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Leftrightarrow x_1 = x_2.$

Therefore, first solve the problem for $g(x) = x^2.$  Here, it is obvious that (assuming that the domain includes all non-negative values of $x$), in order for $g(x)$ to have an inverse, the domain must not include any negative values for $x$.

Then contrast $g(x)$ with $f(x)$ and you will see that the graphs of the two functions are identical except that $f(x)$ has the graph shifted to the left one unit.  Therefore, assuming that the domain of $f(x)$ includes all values of $x \geq -1$, in order for $f(x)$ to have an inverse, its domain **must not also include any values**
of $x < -1.$

Answer (score 0):

$[-1,\infty)$ as this is the largest interval containing zero on which $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ passes the "horizontal line test", and is hence injective.

Answer (score -1):

This is a parabola centered at $(x,y)=(-1,0)$. Notice that both branches are separately invertible. Consider the interval $[-1,\infty)$. This contains $0$ and $f$ is invertible. For any other interval, say, $[a,\infty)$ with $a<-1,$ the function is not one to-one.